# java PrintService, missing MediaSize in getSupportedAttributeValues

Tags: java, printing

In the settings of the printer I made a new Format named custom1 with width 57 and height 100. Also I changed the custom format to the same width and height.

With the following routine I tried to figure out the supported mediasizes:

```java
Media[] res = (Media[])printService.getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, null, null);
for (Media media : res) {
    if (media instanceof MediaSizeName) {
        MediaSizeName msn = (MediaSizeName) media;
        MediaSize ms = MediaSize.getMediaSizeForName(msn);
        float width = ms.getX(MediaSize.MM);
        float height = ms.getY(MediaSize.MM);
        System.out.println("Class:" + msn.getClass().getName()
                            + "; toString:" + msn.toString() + "; width:"
                            + width + "; height:" + height);
    }
}
```

But in the list is neither custom nor custom1. Also about the half number of the formats are missing in the list.

What is the problem? Does this printer not support the MediaSizes in Java?
What can I do?

When I test this on another printer the custom MediaSize with the right width and height is supported. Where is the problem with this printer?

Thanks for all answers